# Sibling view with same elevation within a LinearLayout crossing shadows over

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have two `TextView` within a `LinearLayout` having the same hierarchy and elevation and even though their shadows are getting overlapped.
Take a look at the following image and you will see in both left and right edges two shadows that belong to the bottom edge of the first TextView and another belongs to the top edge of the second TextView.

How can I solve that?

[image]

I do not want to add both views to a ViewGroup with elevation

this is what I want to accomplish

[image]

I will have a list of items, and once the user clicks one, then the item will expand to show more details.

Each item has is on elevation, in order to produce shadow once any other item gets expanded like in the example.

Comment: I'd imagine this is expected behavior. Could you perhaps host the sibling views inside another parent and then apply the elevation to that (single) parent?

Comment: The reason why each element has its own elevation is the user will have the ability to click any of those views and then it will expand vertically and horizontally. If I put the views within a ViewGroup then I will not going to be able of do any horizontally expansion